# How to read Parquet "group"/list field in cpp?

Tags: c++, parquet, apache-arrow

I am new to cpp. I have some Parquet with part of its schema like this:

```
  optional binary one (UTF8);
  optional group two (LIST) {
    repeated group list {
      optional binary element (UTF8);
    }
  }
  optional binary three (UTF8);
```

I'm using Arrow's `parquet::StreamReader` to read it like in [this example](https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/master/cpp/examples/parquet/parquet-stream-api/stream-reader-writer.cc#L238).

It's clear to me how to read fields `one` and `three`, and `one` works fine, but not `two`, so I can't reach `three`. For `two`, I'm not sure what cpp type to use. I know the [logical type is "list"](https://github.com/apache/parquet-format/blob/master/LogicalTypes.md#lists) and below is the output from assigning it into `std::string` just to get the inferred type from the error, but it shows me `'UNKNOWN'`:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type parquet::ParquetException: 
Column physical type mismatch.  Column 'two' has physical type 'UNKNOWN' not 'BYTE_ARRAY'
```

I would just skip this column entirely (I don't require it) but am unclear how I can do that without parsing it.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it is not possible to use `StreamReader` except on primitive types. However, I was able to use [`StreamReader::SkipColumns`](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/cpp/api/formats.html?highlight=skipcolumn#_CPPv4N7parquet12StreamReader11SkipColumnsE7int64_t) to skip `two` and then parse `three`.